# Prove this surface is invariant for the following map

Tags: calculus

I have the following problem:

> Consider the parametric family of maps from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to
>   $\mathbb{R}^3$ $$f_a(x, y, z) = (axy − z, x, y)$$ with
>   $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Prove that the surfaces
>   $x^2+y^2+z^2-axyz=C$, $C\in\mathbb{R}$, are invariant by $f_a$.

We need to take a point $w\in\{x^2+y^2+z^2-axyz=C\}$ and see that $f_a(w)$ satisfies the equation too. However, I'm struggling extracting a generic point that satisfies the equation in order to prove this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x , y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be such that $x ^2 +y ^2 +z ^2-ax y z = C$ holds, now denote the next iterate by $f(x, y, z) = (axy-z, x,y) = (x_1 ,y_1, z_1)$

$x_1 ^2 +y_1 ^2 +z_1 ^2 -ax_1 y_1 z_1 = C$

$(axy-z)^2 +x^2 +y^2 -a(axy-z)xy = C$

$(x^2 +y^2 + z ^2) +a^2 x^2 y^2 -2axyz -(a^2xy-az)xy = C$

$x^2 +y^2 + z^2 -2axyz +axyz = C$

$x^2 + y^2 +z^2 -axyz = C$

If you know how to find all periodic orbits of period 2 let me know (no em surt).

Comment: Haha yes I got periodic orbits of period 2. You need to find fixed points of $f^2$. In this case, we have $$f^2(x,y,z)=(a^2x^2y-axz-y,axy-z,x)$$
Now we need to solve the fixed points of this. First you can use third equation $x=z$ and substitute that into the first and second one. Then, you can get $x=\frac{y}{ay-1}$ from the first one and plug it in the second one to end up getting that $ay^2=0$. That is, either $y=0\Rightarrow (0,0,0)$ fixed point, or $a=0\Rightarrow (k,-k,k)$ fixed point $\forall k\in\mathbb{R}$. (Si no està clar pregunta :) )

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x^2+y^2+z^2-axyz = C$.

Substitute $axy-z$ for $x$, substitute $x$ for $y$, and substitute $y$ for $z$.

Prove $(axy-z)^2 + x^2 + y^2 - a(axy-z)(x)(y)=C$.